# Azure Devops REST API add reviewer to a PR

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, azure-rest-api

I need to add a reviwer to the PR. What I'm trying to do:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/***/***/_apis/git/repositories/***/pullRequests/47108/reviewers/${reviwerID}?api-version=6.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -ContentType application/json
```

> Getting error: Invoke-RestMethod:
> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid argument
> value.\r\nParameter name: A valid reviewer must be
> supplied.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException,
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer","typeKey":"InvalidArgumentValueException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

Where ${reviwerID} I tried to use an email/userPrincipalName and ID got from

```
az ad user show --id myemail
```

Nothing works fine except this command:

```
az repos pr reviewer add --id $myemail
```

But I need to use REST API, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find ${reviwerID} through this request: [Get Team Members With Extended Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get-team-members-with-extended-properties?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#examples)

```
$uriGetTeamMembers = "$orgUrl/_apis/projects/$teamProject/teams/$TeamName/members"
$teamMembers = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriGetTeamMembers -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$rvidentity = $teamMembers.value.Where({$_.identity.displayName -eq $rvname})
$rvidentity[0].identity.id
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, thank you very much!
May be you know, does microsoft documentation have related documentation? I have not found any references that reviewer id is not the same as AAD user id.